# .htaccess modrewrite problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I have a website on wordpress and I have written a plugin which required SEO friendly URL now i am stuck at the following

`http://domain.com/catalogue-category/1/` is working fine but when i replace the `/1/` with the name of the category like `http://domain.com/catalogue-category/Seating/` it does not work at all and gives me `404` error.

Its also working at `/catalogue-category/?cat=Seating`

My apache rewrite rule is

```
RewriteRule ^catalogue-category/^([^/]+)/$ /catalogue-category/?cat=$1 [L]
```

I am not that good in mod rewrite as that in PHP, so please bear my ignorance and treat me as a rookie.

Looking forward to hear from the gurus :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^catalogue-category/([^/]+)/$ /catalogue-category/?cat=$1 [L]
```

You were using the caret `^` twice in your regex pattern (`^catalogue-category/^([^/]+)/$`), the caret asserts that the match should be from the start of the string.

### Pattern explanations

#### Previous pattern:

> 1. Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
> 2. Match the characters “catalogue-category/” literally
>    «catalogue-category/»
> 3. Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
> 4. Match the regular expression below and
>    capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^/]+)»
>
>    1. Match
>       any character that is NOT a “/” «[^/]+»
>
>       1. Between one and
>          unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>          (greedy) «+»
> 5. Match the character “/”
>    literally «/»
> 6. Assert position at the end of the string (or
>    before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»

#### Suggested one

> 1. Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
> 2. Match the characters “catalogue-category/” literally
>    «catalogue-category/»
> 3. Match the regular expression below and
>    capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^/]+)»
>
>    1. Match
>       any character that is NOT a “/” «[^/]+»
>
>       1. Between one and
>          unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>          (greedy) «+»
> 4. Match the character “/”
>    literally «/»
> 5. Assert position at the end of the string (or
>    before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»

Comment: thanks for the prompt answer but it did not work :(, still showing 404.

Comment: what i am unsure about is why /1/ is working and why not /Seating/ ,its driving me nuts now :(

Comment: @Tarun Sharma: Then, your problem doesn't lie in `.htaccess` anymore. You should check elsewhere, maybe your `?cat=$1` expects only integers? Have you tried to see on `Firebug->Net` how many and what rewrites are done when you request `/catalogue-category/1/` and `/catalogue-category/Seating/`?

Comment: let me describe you what i am doing. I have written a shortcode in wordpress and placed that shortcode in a page with the URL http://kooldevelopment.com/catalogue-category , here catalog-category is the page's permalink and in that shortcode i am accepting a querystring variable called [cat] so whatever value cat has, it will be matched with the category name entered through my plugin and it display the products in that category.. hope you understand the logic behind it. I am now stuck cauz when i pass /1/ which is the ID, it worked fine but not in cat name like /seating/

Comment: Hmm... Maybe `/1/` is working, because of WP rewriting and not because of the above rewrite rule. It is hard to tell what is failing here. That's I told you to see how many rewrites are done to the request. If you have a live example of this, please share it with us.

Comment: I can share my .htaccess with you, find it below
[code]<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteRule ^catalogue-category/(.*)/$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^catalogue-category/([^/]+)/$ /catalogue-category/?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product-details/(.*)/$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>[/code]

Comment: There is definitely nothing wrong with your `.htaccess`, the problem must lie somewhere else. I tried to replicate the problem on a local WP install with your `.htaccess` by creating the folder `catalogue-category` and putting inside it an `index.php` with the code `<?php echo 'Cat: '.$_GET['cat']; ?>`, then by accessing `/catalogue-category/anything/` I would see `Cat: anything` as output. Thus, your `.htaccess` is rewriting just fine. Please share your code for the short-code functionality or part of it, so we can test.